# why am I getting double free or corruption (!prev) and segmentation fault in my c program?

Tags: c, list, memory, free

I am trying to write an intrusion detection system in c where I have a linked list of detectors and in each element inside detectors list I have a list of memory_cells and best_detector.

But I am getting two types of erros: double free or corruption (!prev) and segmentation fault

I made a research and I know that the first one is caused by trying to free the same address of a pointer twice. And the second is caused when I try to access a memory position which is not initialized.

I have been trying to figure out why this happens in my code but I don't understand why. Below is my code; I commented the lines of code where the errors occur like this -> // ERROR 1 // ERROR 2

Lists are made from the struct Node like in the Data.h file:

```
#ifndef DATA
#define DATA
 
#include <stdbool.h>
 
struct Node{
     
    double pattern[19];
    double bitstring[19];
    double affinity;
    double fitness;
    double radius;  
    double cost;
     
    bool instance_class; // normal-> false / anomaly-> true
     
    int counter;
    int correct; // Number of anomalies correctly identified
    int confirm;
         
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* memory_cells;
    struct Node* best_detector;
         
    };
 
typedef struct cells{
 
     double pattern[19];
     int confirm;
 
}cells; 
     
#endif
```

delete_list method:

```
void delete_list(struct Node** head_ref)
{
   /* deref head_ref to get the real head */
   struct Node* current = *head_ref;
   struct Node* next;
 
   while (current != NULL) 
   {
       next = current->next; // ERROR 2
       free(current); //ERROR 1
       current = next; 
   }
    
   /* deref head_ref to affect the real head back
      in the caller. */
   *head_ref = NULL;
}
```

delete_note_list method:

```
void delete_node_list(struct Node** list){
 
    struct Node* temp = *list;
 
    while(*list != NULL){
 
        delete_list(&((*list)->memory_cells)); // ERROR 1
        delete_list(&((*list)->best_detector)); // ERROR 2
 
        *list = (*list)->next;   
    }
 
    *list = temp;
 
    delete_list(list);
 
}
```

insert_list method:

```
void insert_list(struct Node** list, double detector[SIZE]){
     
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
         
        temp -> pattern[i] = detector[i];
        temp -> bitstring[i] = doubleToBinary(detector[i]);
         
        }
 
    temp->memory_cells = NULL;
    temp->best_detector = NULL; 
 
        temp->affinity = 0.0;
        temp->fitness = 0.0;
        temp->radius = 0.0;
        temp->cost = 0.0;
 
        temp->counter = 0;
        temp->correct = 0;
        temp->confirm = 0;
                                     
    temp -> next = *list;
    *list = temp;
             
    }
```

insert_memory_cells method:

```
void insert_memorycell(struct Node** list, double pattern[SIZE]) {
     
    struct Node* cell = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
     
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
         
        cell -> pattern[i] = pattern[i];
        cell -> bitstring[i] = doubleToBinary(pattern[i]);
                 
        }
 
    cell->memory_cells = NULL;
    cell->best_detector = NULL;
 
    cell->affinity = 0.0;
    cell->fitness = 0.0;
    cell->radius = 0.0;
    cell->cost = 0.0;
 
    cell->counter = 0;
    cell->correct = 0;
    cell->confirm = 0;
      
    cell->next = (*list)->memory_cells;
    (*list)->memory_cells = cell;
}
```

insert_best_detector method:

```
void insert_best_detector(struct Node** list, double pattern[SIZE]) {
     
    struct Node* cell = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
     
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
         
        cell -> pattern[i] = pattern[i];
        cell -> bitstring[i] = doubleToBinary(pattern[i]);
         
        }
 
    cell->memory_cells = NULL;
    cell->best_detector = NULL;
 
    cell->affinity = 0.0;
    cell->fitness = 0.0;
    cell->radius = 0.0;
    cell->cost = 0.0;
 
    cell->counter = 0;
    cell->correct = 0;
    cell->confirm = 0;
      
    cell->next = (*list)->best_detector;
    (*list)->best_detector = cell;
}
```

main program:

```
/****************** CLIENT CODE ****************/
 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h> 
 
#include "NSA_NSL_KDD.h"
#include "CLONALG_NSL_KDD.h"
#include "aiNet_NSL_KDD.h"
#include "SortingLists.h"
#include "TCPClient.h"
#include "TCPCommunication.h"
 
#define TRUE   1 
#define FALSE  0 
#define PORT 9005 
 
 
#define MAX_DETECTORS 300
 
void initialization_phase(struct Node** detectors, struct  Node** recv_memory_cells, struct Node* self_dataset, int iteration, int max_detectors){
     
    int received_antigen = list_size(*recv_memory_cells);
     
    if(iteration == 0){
         
        negative_selection(detectors, self_dataset, max_detectors);
         
        }else{
 
                        //insert received memory cells in detectors list 
 
                struct Node* temp = *recv_memory_cells;
 
                while(temp != NULL){
 
                        insert_list(detectors, temp->pattern); 
 
                set_detector_radius(detectors, self_dataset);
                              
                        temp = temp->next;
 
                }
 
                delete_node_list(recv_memory_cells);
     
            negative_selection(detectors, self_dataset, max_detectors - received_antigen);
                     
             }
     
             
}
 
void detection_phase(struct Node** detectors, struct Node* dataset){ //Negative selection
         
    struct Node * temp = *detectors;
    struct Node * temp2 = dataset;
     
    while(*detectors != NULL){
 
        while(dataset != NULL){
             
            if(euclidian_distance(dataset->pattern, (*detectors)->pattern) < (*detectors)->radius){
                 
                (*detectors)->counter += 1; 
                insert_memorycell(detectors, dataset->pattern);
                 
                if(dataset->instance_class)
                    (*detectors)->correct += 1;
                 
                }
                 
                dataset = dataset->next;
             
            }
 
            *detectors = (*detectors)->next;
            dataset = temp2;
         
        }
     
     *detectors = temp;
     
    }       
 
void calculation_phase(struct Node** detectors, char* file_name){
     
    int lines = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
     
    int self_antigen_num = 0;
    int non_self_antigen_num = 0;
     
    char * lastAttribute;
     
    FILE * f_Calculation_Phase_Pointer = fopen(file_name, "r");
     
    lineCount = GetFileLines(file_name);
         
    struct Node* temp = *detectors;
     
    // get self_antigen_num and non_self_antigen_num values
         
    while(lines < lineCount){
                 
        lastAttribute = GetInstanceClass(&f_Calculation_Phase_Pointer);
                                 
        lines++;
                 
                if(strncmp(lastAttribute,"normal",6) == 0)      
            self_antigen_num++;
        else
            non_self_antigen_num++;
                     
            }
             
    printf("\nself antigen num: %d\n", self_antigen_num);
    printf("non self antigen num: %d\n", non_self_antigen_num);     
     
    // calculate each detector's fitness        
     
    while(*detectors != NULL){
                                 
        if(non_self_antigen_num > 0)
            (*detectors)->fitness = (double)(*detectors)->correct/(double)non_self_antigen_num; 
        else
            (*detectors)->fitness = 0.0;
         
        *detectors = (*detectors)->next;
                 
        }
                 
        *detectors = temp;
         
        fclose(f_Calculation_Phase_Pointer);
     
    }
     
void selection_phase(struct Node* detectors, struct Node** best_detectors, struct Node** judgment_agents){
 
    struct Node* temp = detectors;
             
    double max_fitness = 0.0;
    int counter = 0;
     
    int max_counter = 0; // to select judgment_agents
 
    // find max fitness value
 
    while(detectors != NULL){
         
        if(detectors->fitness > max_fitness)
            max_fitness = detectors->fitness;
             
        if(max_counter < detectors->counter)
            max_counter = detectors->counter;
             
        detectors = detectors->next;
         
        }
 
        detectors = temp;
        
    //find best detectors with the highest fitness  
         
    while(detectors != NULL){
         
        if(detectors->fitness == max_fitness){
             
            insert_list(best_detectors, detectors->pattern);
            (*best_detectors)->counter = detectors->counter;
            (*best_detectors)->fitness = detectors->fitness;
            (*best_detectors)->radius = detectors->radius;
 
            struct Node* temp2 = detectors->memory_cells;
 
            while(detectors->memory_cells != NULL){ 
 
                insert_memorycell(best_detectors, detectors->memory_cells->pattern);
                 
                detectors->memory_cells = detectors->memory_cells->next;
                 
                }
                 
                detectors->memory_cells = temp2;
             
            }
             
            detectors = detectors->next;
         
        }
 
        //find best detector 
         
        if(list_size(*best_detectors) > 1){
             
            struct Node* temp2 = NULL;
 
            while(*best_detectors != NULL){
                 
                if((*best_detectors)->counter >= counter){
                     
                    counter = (*best_detectors)->counter;
                    temp2 = *best_detectors;
                     
                    }                   
                 
                *best_detectors = (*best_detectors)->next;
                 
                }
                 
                //list best_detectors with only the best detector
                 
                delete_node_list(best_detectors);
                *best_detectors = temp2;    
                delete_node_list(&((*best_detectors)->next));
             
            }
         
        //select judgment agents
         
        detectors = temp;   
             
        int n = list_size(detectors)/2;
                 
        int i = 0;
                 
        while(i < n){
         
            while(detectors != NULL){
 
                int c = 0;
 
                                if(max_counter > 0)
                    c = rand()%max_counter;
             
                if(detectors->counter >= c && !euclidian_distance_match_list(*judgment_agents, detectors->pattern, 0.0)
                && !cell_equal((*best_detectors)->pattern, detectors->pattern)){
                 
                    insert_list(judgment_agents, detectors->pattern);
                    i++;
                 
                    }
                 
                detectors = detectors->next;
                         
            }
             
            detectors = temp;           
                 
        }               
    }
 
void detection_phase_2(struct Node** judgment_agents, struct Node** detectors, struct Node* best_detector){ //clonal selection
     
    struct Node* temp = *judgment_agents;
 
    while(*judgment_agents != NULL){ //informed by best detector
 
        insert_best_detector(judgment_agents, best_detector->pattern);               
        *judgment_agents = (*judgment_agents)->next;
         
        }
     
    *judgment_agents = temp; 
             
    while(*judgment_agents != NULL){ //Mutating -> Moving near best agent
                                         
        //mutating one clone instance in clones each time function is called
             
        hypermutate(judgment_agents);
                                 
        *judgment_agents = (*judgment_agents)->next;
                 
        } 
             
    *judgment_agents = temp;
 
    //Sorting by fitness and fixing agents control population
     
    sort_fitness(detectors);
         
    }
 
void judgment_phase(struct Node** judgment_clones, struct Node** memory_cells, struct Node* self_dataset){ //Immune Network
     
    //set judgment_clones radius
     
    struct Node* temp = *judgment_clones;
     
    while(*judgment_clones != NULL){
         
        set_detector_radius(judgment_clones, self_dataset);     
        *judgment_clones = (*judgment_clones)->next;
         
        }
         
    *judgment_clones = temp;
         
    struct Node* temp2 = *memory_cells;
     
    while(*judgment_clones != NULL){
         
        while(*memory_cells != NULL){
             
            if(euclidian_distance((*judgment_clones)->pattern, (*memory_cells)->pattern) < (*judgment_clones)->radius)
                (*memory_cells)->confirm += 1;
             
            *memory_cells = (*memory_cells)->next;
             
            }
             
        *memory_cells = temp2;  
        *judgment_clones = (*judgment_clones)->next; 
         
        }
         
    *judgment_clones = temp;
    *memory_cells = temp2;
     
    sort_confirm(memory_cells);
     
    }
 
 
int main(){
 
  srand ( time(NULL) );
 
  struct Node* detectors = NULL;
  struct Node* self_dataset = NULL; 
  struct Node* train_dataset = NULL; 
  struct Node* best_detector = NULL;
  struct Node* judgment_agents = NULL;
 
  struct Node* recv_memory_cells = NULL; 
 
  struct Node* final_detectors = NULL;
 
  double max_fitness = 0.0;
 
  const int max_detectors = 150; //Number of cells to send or receive
   
  //generate datasets...
    
  generate_dataset(&self_dataset, "Self_Dataset.txt");
   
  generate_dataset(&train_dataset, "Dataset.txt");
 
  start_connection();
 
  double accuracy = -1;
 
  for(int iteration = 0; iteration < ITERATIONS; iteration++){
   
 
    printf("\niteration: %d\n", iteration);
         
    //delete lists
     
    if(iteration != 0){
 
            delete_node_list(&detectors); // ERROR 2 
 
            delete_node_list(&judgment_agents);
 
            delete_node_list(&best_detector); // ERROR 1 when iteraton == 1
    }
 
        //--- deleted lists
     
    initialization_phase(&detectors, &recv_memory_cells, self_dataset, iteration, max_detectors);
 
    detection_phase(&detectors, train_dataset);
 
    calculation_phase(&detectors, "Dataset.txt");
 
    selection_phase(detectors, &best_detector, &judgment_agents);   
 
    if(get_detectors_accuracy(detectors, train_dataset) > get_detectors_accuracy(final_detectors, train_dataset)){
 
        delete_node_list(&final_detectors);
 
        struct Node* temp = detectors;
         
        while(temp != NULL){
 
            insert_list(&final_detectors, temp->pattern);
 
            final_detectors->fitness = temp->fitness;
            final_detectors->counter = temp->counter;
            final_detectors->correct = temp->correct;
            final_detectors->radius = temp->radius;
         
            temp = temp->next;           
        }
 
    }
 
    detection_phase_2(&judgment_agents, &detectors, best_detector);
     
    judgment_phase(&judgment_agents, &best_detector->memory_cells, self_dataset);
 
    client(best_detector->memory_cells, &recv_memory_cells, max_detectors);
 
  }
 
  close_client();
 
  sort_fitness(&final_detectors);
 
  printf("\nFINAL DETECTORS\n\n");
  print_list(final_detectors);
 
  print_detectors_performance(final_detectors, train_dataset);
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the lines with errors in the main program are right at the beginning of the main block  inside "if(iteration != 0)" two lines only...

Comment: all the time I insert or delete a list I use the methods insert_list, delete_list, delete_node_list, insert_memory_cells, and insert_best_detector. So if there is any mistakes they should be inside those methods... but I allways initialize all lists with NULL so I don't get it.....